# Encrypt passwords

Tags: encryption, passwords, md5

I have a problem with a script. When recording a new user password is recorded normally. I tried to encrypt with MD5 or sha1, is properly encrypted in the database, but it is automatically changed the value of the password. For example:

If I register with the password "mypassword", in the database is encrypted properly. But if I log out, and then I connect again by entering the password "mypassword", does not recognize it more, but recognizes only one encrypted.

It is not normal do so. I try to paste some code.

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../_database/database.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['signup_button'])){
    $user_email = $_REQUEST['user_email'];
    $user_firstname = $_REQUEST['user_firstname'];
    $user_lastname = $_REQUEST['user_lastname'];
    $user_username = $_REQUEST['user_username'];
    $user_password = $_REQUEST['user_password'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO user(user_firstname,user_lastname,user_email,user_username,user_password,user_joindate,user_avatar) VALUES('$user_firstname','$user_lastname','$user_email','$user_username', '$user_password',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'default.jpg')";
        mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($database));
        $_SESSION['user_username'] = $user_username;
        header('Location: ../update-profile-after-registration.php?user_username='.$user_username);
    }
?>
```

And,

```
           <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" action="components/registration.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="row">     
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="z-index: 9;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" name="user_firstname" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="z-index: 9;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name" name="user_lastname" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             <div class="row">     
                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" name="user_email" required>
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">   
                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <!-- http://<?php echo $rws['domain_websiteaddress'];?>/user_username= --> know.me/
                            </span>
                            <input type="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="username" name="user_username" id="user_username" required> 
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="status"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </div>     
                </div>
                <div class="row">     
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="pasword" name="user_password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in" type="submit"  id="SubmitButton" value="Upload" style="float:left;" name="signup_button"/>Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: `MD5` and `SHA1` are *not* encryption algorithms. They are *hash algorithms*. Also *neither* should be used any longer. They are insecure.

Comment: Please have a look at the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and the [password_verify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions, they are appropriate to hash passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried password_hash but it gave me error. Could you do me a quick example?

Answer (score 0):

The hash algorithms MD5 and SHA-* are not appropriate to hash passwords, because they are too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily. Instead one should use slow hash functions with a cost factor:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

This example shows how to use the PHP function password_hash() and password_verify(). They will produce a salted BCrypt hash.

EDIT:

Ok i will try to do the modifications in your example code. Note that i used prepared statements, because your example is prone to SQL-injection. The code is not tested.

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../_database/database.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['signup_button']))
{
  $user_email = $_REQUEST['user_email'];
  $user_firstname = $_REQUEST['user_firstname'];
  $user_lastname = $_REQUEST['user_lastname'];
  $user_username = $_REQUEST['user_username'];
  $user_password = $_REQUEST['user_password'];
  $passwordHash = password_hash($user_password);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO user(user_firstname,user_lastname,user_email,user_username,user_password,user_joindate,user_avatar) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'default.jpg')";
  $stmt = $database->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $user_firstname, $user_lastname, $user_email, $user_username, $passwordHash);
  $stmt->execute();

  $_SESSION['user_username'] = $user_username;
  header('Location: ../update-profile-after-registration.php?user_username='.$user_username, true, 303);
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Could you tell me exactly where to place these variables? Could you give me an example about my case?